# Adode CC createjs ticker examples

Tags: javascript, animation, adobe, createjs, easeljs

ive got a button in Adobe CC anime , which has a listener on it, to play music everytime i press it. Code is that :

```
   this.playmusic.addEventListener("click", loadHandler.bind(this));
function loadHandler() {

     createjs.Sound.stop();
     createjs.Sound.play("soundenergy");
 }
```

but i want when i click on the button and music starts to be a setInterval(?) which makes it clickable or playable after 10 seconds or less/more.

i was thinking something about that , but i cant figure it out:

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", loadHandler);
this.playmusic.addEventListener("click", loadHandler.bind(this));
function loadHandler() {
     Ticker._interval = 50;
     createjs.Sound.stop();
     createjs.Sound.play("soundenergy");
 }
```

Comment: "...which makes it clickable or playable after 10 seconds or less/more". Maybe what are you're looking for it, it's not a `setInterval()` method, but instead, a `setTimeout()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using the EaselJS Ticker class. It is used for an application heartbeat, and currently only supports one global ticker. If you set the interval, it will affect all animations, tweens, etc.

If you want to have something happen, you could store the previous time, and then check the next time to determine how often you want something to happen:

```
var lastTime = 0;
function tick(event) {

    // Check the time diff
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    if (time > lastTime + 5000) {
        // Do something every 5 seconds
        makeEnemy();
        lastTime = time;
    }

    // Update the stage
    stage.update(event);
}
```

Otherwise, @CrisMVP3200 comment is right. Consider using `setInterval` for a repeating event, and `setTimeout` for a single asynchronous callback after a delay.

Cheers.